# Trying to identify the cause of this display corruption

Tags: display, video, gpu

I don't actually know where the root cause of this issue lies or even how to accurately describe it so I will do my best to provide the details of the situation. Hopefully someone will have a better understanding than I do, of what this problem is.

my hardware

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate
- CPU: i7 3820
- RAM: 16GB
- GPU: GTX 970
- GeForce Driver version: 347.25
- Monitor: ASUS ROG Swift on Display port
- Monitor: LG IPS screen on DVI
- Monitor: TV on HDMI
- ROG swift Resolution: 2560x1440
- ROG swift Refresh: 144Hz

my observations

- When the issue starts I've only been able to fix it with a system reboot.
- I haven't found a way to make the issue happen at will.
- It happens most often when the monitor comes out of power saving mode.
- None of the other displays that are plugged in display the issue
- Power cycling the ROG Swift does not fix the issue.
- Unplugging any monitor when the issue is occurring results in all video output stopping until the system is rebooted.

example of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Isn't that about 3times as much 'work' or bandwidth occurring for the GPUs screen buffer rams to feed the monster monitor? If your gpu cooling fan was manually set to full speed , or bearably fast, and not reduced any in speed when in standby , I wonder if it would come out of standby everytime without a glitch.

Comment: I've had this problem and a (slightly) easier workaround I've found is to adjust the monitor's resolution to a different setting, then change it back. Somehow that gets it to refresh enough to lose the weird ghosting/double image. http://superuser.com/questions/895114/blurred-fuzzy-doubled-image/895115

Comment: Thanks for the link Joe. Its actually been happening quite a bit less these days. I'm going to be doing an OS update to Win 8.1 if not Win 10 soon so I'll be interested to see if that changes anything.