# Blurred/fuzzy/doubled image

Tags: windows-7, display, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I built a new PC for Christmas. In the three months since then, I've had this problem occur 4-5 times. After letting my computer sit for a while, such that it turns off the display, and coming back, the image will appear distorted, as if there are two images that are a bit out of sync, creating a jagged, fuzzy appearance to my entire desktop.

The interesting thing is, if I start a game that is full screen, it will appear normal, but when I exit back to the desktop, it will still be fuzzy. All windowed applications appear fuzzy too.

I am running a Windows 7 fully updated OS, with an EVGA nVidia GTX 760 video card and an ASUS VG248QE 24" monitor that is connected via a displayport cable.

My questions are: what is the cause, can this be prevented, and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have the correct driver for the GPU and maybe even for the monitor installed?

Comment: it is an issue with the video cards screen buffer thing in the V-ram. It is possible that an updated driver may have attempted solution, by changing the way it comes back out of standby (more carefully). It is a big jolt to kick this stuff back in when off, it is possible a PSU could be involved. Any Overclocking of the PCI-E buss (BCLK) could make something like this more apt to occur. Any overclocking of the video card itself, could be stopped prior to entering standby then restarted after comming out.  Better cooling of the V-Ram might help.  I have solved it before (uhhh i forget)

Comment: @TheUser1024 oh I forgot to include that. I keep the nVidia drivers up-to-date, and this has happened with two different versions. As far as I know, there aren't drivers specific for that model of monitor. There is no more recent version of the generic Windows driver for it.

Comment: @Psycogeek thanks for the information. Since it happens so rarely it's hard to find a pattern. Neither the video card nor the buss are overclocked. I'm wondering if it occurs when the room gets too warm.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/872073/trying-to-identify-the-cause-of-this-display-corruption#comment1160115_872073  Is this the same kind of thing as you were seeing?  Otherwise a picture taken of your screen if it is different.   You can also do a "printscreen" or screen grab which should NOT show a problem, proving (more) that it is happening at the end hardware.

Comment: @Psycogeek Yes, that's exactly the same as what happens to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two ways to fix the problem, neither of which is ideal.

1) Restart the computer.

2) Change the resolution to another setting, then change it back.